# Should dispose NsUrl after opening url in Xamarin iOS?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have this piece of code:

```
public void Launch(Uri uri) 
{
   using (NSUrl nsUrl = new NSUrl(uri.AbsoluteUri))
   {
       UIApplication.SharedApplication.OpenUrl(nsUrl);
   }
}
```

Does above code is correct (and necessary) to release `nsUrl` after opening url ?

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do anything else. `nsUrl` is automatically disposed at the end of the using statement.

See Microsoft's explination [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

After seeing your edit: Yes, this is correct. NSUrl implements iDisposable. You can find the Xamarin documentation for NSUrl [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Foundation.NSUrl/).

Comment: @SnakeEyes Ahh, ok! I updated my answer. Basically, a using statement ensures correct use of an IDisposable object, and since NSUrl implements IDisposable, this the correct practice.